# PHP - get and print age of email (sent from contact form)

Tags: php, date, time, date-arithmetic

So I have a contact form... The mail it sends looks like so:

```
<h1>MSG from Website</h1>
<p>Some Text</p>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10">
  <tr bgcolor="#DFEFF0">
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><?=$name;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#BDD8DA">
    <th>Email-Adresse</th>
    <td><?=$email;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#DFEFF0">
    <th>Telefonnummer</th>
    <td><?=$phone;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#BDD8DA">
    <th>telefonisch erreichbar</th>
    <td>von <?=$r_from;?> bis <?=$r_to;?> Uhr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#DFEFF0">
    <th>Betreff</th>
    <td><?=$subject;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#BDD8DA">
    <th>Nachricht</th>
    <td><?=$msg;?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to add to the content of the email are two php time objects. One should display the date and time of when the mail was sent. I use `<?=date("j.n.Y G:i");?>`...
The second time object should show the current system time of the email-recipient...
I plan on doing some maths with those two time objects :)

But my problem is that I don't see how to show the current time... Maybe it's not even possible? Can I view an email in Gmail for example and have a line of php the body of that mail showing me my current time?

Comment: Emails are just static text, unless you're embedding HTML in them, it's just going to display what was sent in the original email; nothing related to when the recipient is opening it.

Comment: This is correct. About the only thing you could do is, in the email, prompt the user to open a full web page where you can display the current time.  I am not sure what this will do for you though.

Comment: Arite, got it, no calculations in emails, just static text :)
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

As you send HTML_Mails you can embed an `<img>` tag. The image tag calls a php-script on your server that delivers the time as an image. But this will only deliver time of the sending server and you can't do any calculations with it. Another option might be the usage of JavaScript, if allowed and available on client-side.

Comment: Good to know about the workarounds but for now I don't need to go as far to do the little thing I wanted, that's why I was hoping for a little inline code solution. But it's fine for me, if it's not possible to do it like that as I expected to get that kind of information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An email is just some static text. No matter what code you use to produce it, you'll end up with a plain message that can't execute any other commands or do anything else once it's been sent. Unless a user's mail client has some special feature for it, there's no way to put a line in an email that will show the current time at the moment the user is viewing it.

To engage in further interaction with the user, you'd need to put a link in the email that directs them to your website. The link could contain the ID of the message, so the page on your site could then look up when it was sent and compare it to the current time.

Comment: Understood. What I was trying to do is nothing too important so I can live without it. Giving the user external links is not what I need, that would be way too much for a little feature I wanted :)
Thanks for your answer